# django error >>> Poll.objects.get(pub_date_year=current_year) while trying tutoria01

Tags: python, django, django-models

In tutorial 01 when i tried this command on python shell , i got following error:

```
from django.utils import timezone
current_year=timezone.now().year
Poll.object.get(pub_date_year=current_year)
```

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 151, in
 get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 301, in g
et
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 593, in f
ilter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 611, in _
filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1204,
 in add_q
    clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1240,
 in _add_q
    current_negated=current_negated)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1103,
 in build_filter
    allow_explicit_fk=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1363,
 in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, allow_explicit_fk)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1283,
 in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'pub_date_year' into field. Choices are: choi
ce, id, pub_date, question
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a double underscore after the field name.

Replace:

```
Poll.object.get(pub_date_year=current_year)
```

with:

```
Poll.object.get(pub_date__year=current_year)
```

See also: [`year` field lookup documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year).

Answer (score 1):

You have a minor typo

```
Poll.object.get(pub_date_year=current_year)
```

should be

```
Poll.object.get(pub_date__year=current_year)
#-----------------------^ 2 __
```

`__` is a syntax to follow fields used in django.